# How to access PWM back light driver?

Tags: arm, embedded-linux

I am using iMX6Q SD board. And I have to access the back light driver to control back lite contrast. How can I access from User space or Kernel space? (Back light PWM driver path is `drivers/video/backlight/pwm_bl.c`). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd expect something like a `sysfs` entry at `/sys/class/backlight/<some name>/brightness` (which you can read or write as an ordinary file, at least from userspace).

Comment: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-class-backlight (there's no `uevent` there, I believe it's the part of generic plug-n-play machinery, unrelated to backlight as such)

Comment: How is the description linked above insufficient? (Maybe you never used sysfs entries like this? You just write a string representation of a number to a "file" to set a parameter, and read it from that "file" to examine a parameter. As of parameter meaning, see "sysfs-class-backlight" description above).

Comment: yes. I can able to read and write using cat and echo. And I have one more quire that this is the only functionality it(driver) will give?

Comment: If you want to understand what this particular driver can do, read it's code, which you apparently have...

Comment: @Anton Kovalenko: Thanks for the info.                                @ Chris Stratton: Yes, I am looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sysfs is the interface for the misc drivers.